# VBA look up/find value matching a date variable and return the date next to it

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I can't seem to solve what seems to be a minor issue. I basically need to open another file, match the datetime stored in a variable with a date in the opened file, then return the datetime four cells to the right.

I've used both of these formulas but neither seem to work:

[Variables]

```
Dim TDate As Date
TDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Static Data").Range("B1").value
Filename = "<filename>"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Filename, UpdateLinks:=False
```

[Formula 1]

```
rundate = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDate(TDate), ActiveWorkbook.Sheet("Dates").Range("B:F"), 4, False).value
```

[Formula 2]

```
Dim TDate As Date
TDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Static Data").Range("B1").value

rundate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet("Dates").Cells.Find(Format(TDate, "d-mmm-yy"), ActiveWorkbook.Sheet("Dates").Range("B1"), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False).value
runtime = rundate.Offset(0, 4).value
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: ensure that both TDate and rundate cells have same format.

Comment: Have you verified that a worksheet `vlookup` will find the value?  Sometimes dates can be tricky since they are really just serial numbers - try switching to general formatting.  Also, what's `CDate`?

Comment: @CRUTER [`CDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2(v=vs.84).aspx) converts a string to a numeric value (while it is *marked* as a date and will return something that looks like a string when used with `debug.print`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worksheet's [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) returns a value, not a cell reference that you need to get the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) from.

`TDate` is already a date but you can also use the raw long integer value.

You need a [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508.aspx), not a `Sheet`.

```
rundate = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(TDate), ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dates").Range("B:F"), 4, False)
```

Comment: This worked! All I had to edit was insert (CLng(CDate(TDate)) instead of TDate. Thank you! Also, just for future reference, why do I need a Worksheets collection instead of Sheet? What is the difference?

Comment: You are identifying a specific worksheet by name so you can use Sheets collection or Worksheets collection but not sheet. tbh, there is no sheet at all. You likely have confused the Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) with the collection(s).

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Thanks again!